# Error: 'cannot GET /' when trying to run a Node.js API with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is the tutorial I'm following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bB7xkRsEq-g

It's a tutorial on how to create your own "ChatGPT"-like site, I have reached the end of the "Frontend React JS component set up" section of the video.

When I run the program, I keep getting an error "`cannot GET /`"

I have tried looking up this error but none of the solutions work. I think I am getting the error because of something to do with the `app.post()` function in index.js (as shown below)

Here is the code so far:

index.js:

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const port = 3001; 

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.post('/', (req,res) => {
    res.json({
        message: "submitted"
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Example app listening at http://localhost:'+ port);
});
```

App.js:

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [response, setResponse] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({message}),
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => setResponse(data.message));
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit = {handleSubmit}>
        <textarea
          value = {message}
          onChange = {(e)=>setMessage(e.target.value)}
        ></textarea>
        <button type = "submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <div>{response}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App
```

Comment: You simply forgot to add a `GET`, you only have `POST`. Add `app.get("/", req, res)` as well. The `POST` route is for POST requests only.

Comment: Where **exactly** do you see the _"cannot GET /"_ error message? How are you running your React app?

Answer (score 0):

The error doesn't necessarily have to be due to `app.post`. You must have gotten `cannot GET /` error when you make a get request to your backend, because there is no Get API route defined in your backend path "`/`".

You can fix it either by updating your frontend request as "`POST`" request (instead of `GET`) or you can define a "`GET`" route in the "`/`" path like below.

```
// Simple GET API to accept GET request in "/" path 
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send("Hey, You are in my backend!!!");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have post app route in your code then you should use `POST`.
But you can also use get method from a small change you can provide `app.post() ===> app.get()` that gives you in image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2CI0.png)

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const port = 3001; 

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.get('/', (req,res) => { // that is the small change
    res.json({
        message: "submitted"
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Example app listening at http://localhost:'+ port);
});
```